# Discord Bot, Embed message wont send to the channel

Tags: java, discord, chatbot, discord-jda

My bot won't display the Embed message in discord. The error that it prints is below the code. It hits the if statement because I put a normal message in there and it displayed that. But the embed message will not display.

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import java.awt.Color;


public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter{
    
    public String prefix = "!";
    
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "test")) {
            
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Stonks Thang", null);
            embed.setDescription("this is the description");
            embed.addField("Embed Feild 1", "This is the field", false);
            embed.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            embed.setFooter("Created by Nick", "");
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
            embed.clear();
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Error That prints out is this

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must be a valid http(s) or attachment url.
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.Checks.check(Checks.java:48)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder.urlCheck(EmbedBuilder.java:801)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder.setFooter(EmbedBuilder.java:694)
    at Commands.onGuildMessageReceived(Commands.java:22)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:466)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:160)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:97)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:952)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:839)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:817)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Comment: The problem with this was the (setFooter) section. The second part of the setFooter is looking for a URL, not an empty string. if you are having this problem too make sure your footer either has a URL in the second part or "null" there.

Comment: Also you should be using `sendMessageEmbeds()` instead and you don't need to call `EmbedBuilder#clear`.

Comment: don't you want to call the clear function so that it clear it for the next run-through?

Comment: You are creating an entirely new builder with clear state each time this code runs, you then call clear and never use it after. This means you clear the builder state for no reason. The entire builder instance will be unreachable the moment your method returns.

Comment: ohhh, gotcha! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```java
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import java.awt.Color;


public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter{
    
    public String prefix = "!";
    
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "test")) {
            
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Stonks Thang");
            embed.setDescription("this is the description");
            embed.addField("Embed Feild 1", "This is the field", false);
            embed.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            embed.setFooter("Created by Nick");
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Both setTitle and setFooter can use 1 arguments instead of 2. Since they will not be set by default if done that way.
Furthermore, everytime your code goes through the EmbedBuilder, it creates a new builder. So you're not required to clear it.

Comment: okay, this makes sense and looks cleaner. Thanks for the help!